# How does the "...also bought"-algorithm work in iTunes for apps

Tags: algorithm, app-store

i was wondering if anyone knew how the "customers also bought" - algorithm works inside the itunes app store. Any chance to manipulate this, so I can show my other apps there?

any hints?

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of the widget, wouldn't it? The only way to "hack" this, is to build apps so cool, that your customers just have to have all of them.

Comment: yeah i thought so. but i also was wondering how this algorithm works in terms of:

- show the newest apps customers bought also
- show the apps with the highest number that customers of your app also bought
- is there a reset?
- ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any chance to manipulate....

### NO!

Read [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/10/serving-at-the-pleasure-of-the-king.html) blog post by Jeff Atwood. They can manipulate you, but you can't manipulate them. Moreover it will be ***wrong*** on your part.

> ***I can show my other apps <s>there</s>?***

Not ***there*** on the itunes app store, but you can show your apps at some point on an interface in your current app. Most apps doing this also provide links to their facebook or twitter pages.

Comment: thanks for the clear feedback! I am already showing/linking my other apps inside the app. But this is of course valuable information to other devs. Just cause i am curious do you know how the algorithm of apple works in more detail?

Comment: @fxmtor. Sorry, I just don't know. We can just speculate. I can think of three things: the *number of users[1]* downloading your previous apps, the *number of well-performing apps[2]* submitted by you and the time since the last app you submitted[3]. [1] The more, the better. [2] Depends on Apple's criteria. [3] Having more recent apps would mean you are active on the market, again decisions will depend on Apple's criteria. All this is ***purely*** speculative though.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts! it definitely seems to make sense this way - but as you said - we can' know for sure :(